# What is the signature of a callable object ? (Bind implementation)

Tags: bind, template-meta-programming, c++98

I'm trying to implement `std::bind` for a school project, and I can pass pointer to functions to it, with 0 to 6 arguments (without placeholders for now). It should be in C++98, I just use auto for now.

It should work too for callable objects, however the compiler disagree with this.
I'm trying to get it work with 0 argument for now.

```
template<typename ReturnType> 
Caller<ReturnType, ReturnType (*)(), typename Traits0::Type>
bind(ReturnType (*f)())
{
  typedef TypeList0 ListType;
  ListType l;
  return Caller<ReturnType, ReturnType (*)(), ListType>(f, l); 
}
```

The compiler says this :

```
main.cpp:54:16: error: no matching function for call to 'bind'
  auto func6 = bind(&c);
           ^~~~
./bind.hpp:19:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'type-parameter-0-0     ()' against 'Callable'
bind(ReturnType (*f)())
```

Is there a different syntax for callable objects, or I just messed up somewhere (Highly probable) ?

My struct Callable :

```
struct Callable
{
  void operator()()
  {
    std::cout << "Structure Callable" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

main.cpp :

```
Callable c;
auto func6 = bind(&c);
```